# Class specific data

Tags: iphone, xcode

using xcode I would like to achieve a public shared class that stores its own data. So, if I'm in one class I can call it from another and retain persistence.

For example,

I have multiple viewcontrollers for an iPhone project. When the app is opened, it checks with a seperate service if that player is logged in and returns some information. Let's call it GamePlacenta. I need to store certain information about the player in the GamePlacenta class, like user_id etc. But I need to be able to access it from any other class later on. I don't want to store it in text files, memory is good.

What do I need to be looking into?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a Singleton.  It does exactly what you want it to--holds one set of data that you can access anywhere.  [Here](http://iphone.galloway.me.uk/iphone-sdktutorials/singleton-classes/) is a great tutorial on creating one.  It's just a few lines of code, and can store anything.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need a Singleton class. See this [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern#Objective-C).